# Is there any possibility to capture an array with all nid of a view?

Tags: views, nodes, hooks

I tried using hooks but  in $view->result variable I only get nodes from the actual page (10 nodes because pager size is 10). My view has multiple exposed filters so I want the resulting nodes from filtering

```
function mymodule_views_pre_view(&$view, &$display_id, &$args){

if ($view->id() == 'myview') {

    foreach ($view->result as $row) {
        // Get the full name value.
        $nid = $row->nid;
        // check the result output for testing only.
        \Drupal::messenger()->addMessage($nid);
    }
```

My ultimate goal is to create a link in that view with concatenated nid argument. Is it possible?

Comment: Curious to know why? What's the purpose of creating such concatinated link?

Comment: I want to create a link to a custom controller in that view: http://example.com/pdf-printer?nodes=1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11+12

Comment: What about creating an additional display in the same view, which is not paginated?